# make a list of recipients to use it at send_mail

Tags: python, django

I'm going to make a list of recipients in `for loop` then use `send_mail` :

```
for participant in participants:
   list.append(participant.mail)
```

then:

```
send_mail(email_subject,email_body,'sender@gmail.com',list,fail_silently=False)
```

what's the right way to make this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you have will work, assuming you define a list to use, first:

```
emails = []
for participant in participants:
    emails.append(participant.email)
```

But, a list comprehension is easier:

```
emails = [p.email for p in participants]
```